# Problema de maior e menor valor com while. (Sem utilizar lista!)

Tags: python, if, while

Escreva um programa que leia um número inteiro N e em seguida leia N 
 números reais, separando o menor e o maior, apresentando-os na tela.

```
N = int(input("Digite N: "))
i = 0
ma = 'maior'
me = 'menor'
me = x
while i < N:
    x = float(input("Digite um número: "))
    ma = x
    me < ma
    i = i + 1
    if x > ma:
        ma = x
    if x < me:
        me = x
print ('O maior valor digitado foi {} e o menor foi {}'.format(ma,me))
```

No programa se pede para que o usuário digite um valor inteiro N para depois ler N números reais e, com isso, mostrar o menor e maior valor dentre aqueles. A questão é que estou fazendo sem utilizar o método de lista. (programação iniciante.) Este código funciona em alguns testes, porém em outros não.
Sei que o problema está na declaração de variavéis ou nas condições das funções if. Porém não enxergo/consigo arrumar esses erros.

Answer (score 6):

Seu código:

```
  1 N = int(input("Digite N: "))                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  2 i = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  3 ma = 'maior'                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  4 me = 'menor'                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  5 me = x                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  6 while i < N:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  7     x = float(input("Digite um número: "))                                                                                                                                                                                   
  8     ma = x                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  9     me < ma                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 10     i = i + 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 11     if x > ma:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 12         ma = x                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 13     if x < me:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 14         me = x                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 15 print ('O maior valor digitado foi {} e o menor foi {}'.format(ma,me))
```

Considerações:

- Nas linhas 3 e 4 você define as variáveis `ma` e `me` como *strings*, o que não faz sentido;
- Já na linha 5 você coloca que `me` será igual à `x`, sendo que o objeto `x` nem está definido ainda;
- Na linha 8, você define que sempre que for lido um novo número, o maior valor, `ma`, será igual a ele; por quê atualizar o valor de `ma` neste ponto?
- Na linha 9 existe uma expressão aleatória que simplesmente não fez sentido nenhum;
- Na linha 11 você compara se o valor lido é maior que `ma`, mas como na linha 8 colocou que `ma = x`, eles sempre serão iguais e, por isso, a condição jamais será satisfeita;

Outras linhas que não comentei até fazem sentido, tais como a leitura de valor de `N`, o laço de repetição `while`, a leitura de `x` e a atualização do menor valor.

Answer (score 0):

Esta implementação resolve:

```
n = int(input("Digite N: "))
ma = None
me = None
for i in range(n):
   x = float(input("Digite um número: "))
   ma = ma if ma != None and ma >  x else x
   me = me if me != None and me < x else x

print ('O maior valor digitado foi {} e o menor foi {}'.format(ma,me))
```

Comment: Por favor, evite responder apenas com códigos. Aquilo que pode ser trivial para você, pode ser complexo para outros usuários, então busque sempre detalhar o melhor possível a solução, inclusive descrevendo-a em texto.

Comment: E sua solução possui uma pequena falha, pois, neste caso, você não pode fazer a condição `if ma` ou `if me` apenas, visto que qualquer valor que é avaliado como falso, tal como 0.0, não a satisfaz. Consequência disso, por exemplo, que se entrar com dois números: `[0.0, -1.0]`, o programa irá acusar -1.0 como o maior ([link](https://ideone.com/xyVxOU)).

Comment: Tem razão... acertei.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 'S'
cont = 0
maior = 0
menor = 0

while x != 'N':
    z = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    cont += 1
    
    if cont == 1:
       maior = z
       menor = z
    else:
        if z > maior:
            maior = z
        if z < menor:
            menor = z

    x = str(input('Deseja continuar? S - Sim / N - Não  ')).upper()

print(f'O MAIOR número digitado foi {maior}.')
print(f'O MENOR número digitado foi {menor}.')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
num = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
maior = num
menor = num

cc = str(input('Deseja continuar? S - Sim / N - Não  ')).upper()

while cc not in 'N':
    num = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    
    if num > maior:
        maior = num
    if maior < menor:
        menor = num

    cc = str(input('Deseja continuar? S - Sim / N - Não  ')).upper()


print('O MAIOR número digitado foi {}.'.format(maior))
print('O MENOR número digitado foi {}.'.format(menor))
```